Transformers error message despite code still running
Currently trying to learn transformers and pytorch in pycharm, had it downloaded using the python interpreter package download
[the downloaded packages](https://i.sstatic.net/DOyxaL4E.png)

yet it keeps getting this error when I run this code


the code still runs, it still outputs the label but I would really like to remove this error at the beginning of the process, I've read one of the solutions from this site and thought it would remove it but it just shows a new error, is there a way to do this?
